# mongodb select nested array with status field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the object below in MongoDB and my back end is using nodeJS. to retrieve the data from DB. the "_id" field is provided in the API body.

```
questions = [
    {
        "_id": "idq1"
        "questiontext": "some question",
        "author": "auth2",
        "Answers": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "idq2"
        "questiontext": "some question",
        "author": "auth1",
        "Answers": [
            {
                "author": "auth1",
                "comments" [...],
                "status" : "1"
            },
            {
                "author": "auth2",
                "comments" [...],
                "status" : "0"
            },
            {
                "author": "auth3",
                "comments" [...],
                "status" : "1"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

Expected result:

I want to get an object where the status is equal to "1" my expected result is given below :

```
    result = {
    "_id": "idq2"
    "questiontext": "some question",
    "author": "auth1",
    "Answers": [
        {
            "author": "auth1",
            "comments" [...],
            "status" : "1"
        },
        {
            "author": "auth3",
            "comments" [...],
            "status" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Understanding the aggregation, it always return an array, so an array should be fine too.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61533627/mongodb-filter-objects-array-content-based-on-object-member/61533804#61533804

Comment: Thank you so much! it was a big help, I change it a bit and it works good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try the solution below and it work!
Thanks to @mickl for his solution on this post: [MongoDB filter objects array content based on object member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61533627/mongodb-filter-objects-array-content-based-on-object-member/61533804#61533804)

```
const question =  await Question.aggregate([

    { $match: {_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}}
    ,{
      $addFields: {
        Answers: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$Answers",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.status",
                "1"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```